# Solving ODEs with Delta Functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

I was given a homework question

> Suppose a bone described by the Kelvin model is deformed by a force
>
> $$F(t)=F_0(\Theta(t)-\Theta(t-\tau)+\Theta(t-2\tau)),$$
>
> where $\Theta$ is the Heaviside function and $F_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant. Find an analytical expression for the response
>   deformation $x(t)$ and sketch it.

Below is what I have done so far, but I'm confused on how to proceed with solving the ODE for the more complicated terms as well as how to combine solutions, especially as we have not looked at using Laplace transforms yet.

Suppose a bone described by the Kelvin model is deformed by a force
$$F(t)=F_0\left(\Theta(t)-\Theta(t-\tau)+\Theta(t-2\tau)\right), $$
where $\Theta$ is the Heaviside function. Then the response deformation $x$ satisfies the differential equation
$$\displaystyle F+\tau_{\epsilon}\frac{dF}{dt}=K_2\left(x+\tau_{\sigma}\frac{dx}{dt}\right). $$

Rewriting using the equation for $F$ gives
$$\begin{align}
\displaystyle x'+ \frac{1}{\tau_{\sigma}}x & =  \displaystyle \frac{F_0}{K_2\tau{\epsilon}}\left(\Theta(t)-\Theta(t-\tau)+\Theta(t-2\tau)\right) \\
& + \displaystyle \frac{F_0\tau_\epsilon}{K_2\tau_\sigma}\left(\delta(t)-\delta(t-\tau)+\delta(t-2\tau)\right)
\end{align}
$$

For $t\leq 0$, the equation becomes 
$$\displaystyle x'+ \frac{1}{\tau_{\sigma}}x=0 $$
which has solution $$x(t)=\displaystyle C_1\exp\left({\frac{t}{\tau_\sigma}}\right).$$

For $0 < t < \tau$, the equation becomes
$$ \displaystyle x'+\frac{1}{\tau_{\sigma}}x=\frac{F_0}{K_2\tau{\epsilon}}+\frac{F_0\tau_\epsilon}{K_2\tau_\sigma} \delta(t)$$
which has solution 
$$\displaystyle x(t)=\frac{F_0\tau_{\sigma}}{K_2\tau{\epsilon}}+C_1\exp\left({\frac{t}{\tau_\sigma}}\right)+\frac{F_0\tau_\epsilon}{K_2\tau_\sigma}\Theta(t)\exp\left({\frac{t}{\tau_\sigma}}\right).$$

Comment: Minor thing: I got confused as to whether $F_0$ is a function or a constant.

Comment: That said this can be done without Laplace transforms but it is a bit tedious to do all the gluing of the different pieces (i.e. solving for the integration constants on each interval).

Answer (score 1):

You can completely avoid going over the Dirac-delta terms.

Your equation has the form $x+ax'=c(F'+bF)$, $x(t)=0=F(t)$ for $t<0$. Now apply the integrating factor $e^{at}$ and compress the right side by a similar factor
$$
(e^{at}x(t))'=ce^{(a-b)t}(e^{bt}F(t))'
$$
and apply the product rule/partial integration
$$
e^{at}x(t)=ce^{at}F(t)-c(a-b)\int_0^te^{as}F(s)\,ds
$$
Now use that 
$$
\int_0^te^{as}Θ(s−τ)\,ds = Θ(t−τ)\frac{e^{a(t-τ)}-1}a
$$
to compose the solution
\begin{align}
x(t)&=cF_0 Θ(t)\left[1+(b-a)\frac{1-e^{-at}}a\right]
\\&\quad
-cF_0 Θ(t−τ)\left[1+(b-a)\frac{e^{-aτ}-e^{-at}}a\right]
\\&\quad
+cF_0 Θ(t−2τ)\left[1+(b-a)\frac{e^{-2aτ}-e^{-at}}a\right]
\end{align}

---

Another variation is to observe that
$$
(x-cF)'+a(x-cF)=c(b-a)F\implies \Bigl(e^{at}(x-cF)\Bigr)'=c(b-a)e^{at}F
$$
which avoids the partial integration step.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would plot $x$ against $t$?

Comment: You need to code the unit ramp function and then can plot the formula as it is. I do not know what tool you use and what specific difficulty you have.